# What is the role of discontinuous surfaces on the inside and outside elevons of the F-117?

Tags: aircraft-design, stealth, f-117

[image]

Why are there discontinuous surfaces on the inside and outside elevons of the stealth F-117? Will that not be highly reflective to the radar?

Comment: Yes, you want a knife edge on those surfaces, not a flat panel, for lower radar returns.

Comment: Can you please circle what you are talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are referring to the gaps between the elevons and the other control surfaces?  Those are called cats eye gaps and they’re used to reduce radar returns between the gaps.  Virtually all stealth aircraft use this technology.